# Contractor not using thin set between sub floor and cement board

Tags: ceramic-tile, contractors

So, I've made a big stink with the flooring guys about how they have installed the [Hardiebacker cement board](https://www.jameshardie.com/Products/HardieBacker-Cement-Board) for our tile.  They skipped putting down the thin set under the cement board even though the [installation instruction](http://www.jameshardie.com/d2w/installation/hardiebacker-us-en.pdf) specify that it is required.

from instructions:

`Apply a supporting bed of mortar or modified thinset to subfloor using a 1/4” square-notched trowel.`

The flooring guy called me and said that JamesHardie company tech support said that if he used screws instead of nails they could forego the thin set under the cement board.

So I called JamesHardie tech support and their offices are currently closed... So I can't verify this claim.  This seems quite shady.

**Am I wrong to push the issue or should I just let him use the screws and go about the job?  They have umpteen years experience doing this stuff.**

**Also,  will this cause problems down the road, and should I continue pushing the issue?**

Comment: Tell them that you can't currently confirm, so they can go ahead, but if you later find from JamesHardie that they're wrong they'll have a big rework project on their hands.

Comment: @Daniel Griscom Yeah that's what I was thinking too.

Comment: Most contractors dont use thinset just screws. but the floor will be much stronger (less chance of cracking a tile if something is dropped on it) if thinset and screws are used.

Comment: It's not so much a matter as what's required as it's about what makes a good finished job. Will dry-setting the cementboard result in creaks or other noise? That would be my main concern.

Comment: @isherwood I agree but the only argument I have for them doing more work is the requirements specified by the manufacturer.  My question is just what you asked, will this cause problems down the road from a professional's point of view and should I continue pushing the issue?  I'll add that to the post.

Comment: What subfloor material? You wouldn't be able to mortar against OSB anyway.

Comment: @isherwood it's 3/4" particle board

Comment: No it isn't. Particle board is not a subfloor material. http://www.diy-live.com/particle.html I haven't seen particle board installed in new construction since the 80s.

Comment: @isherwood yes I think you are right.  I looked up osb and checked a couple pictures, it looks like OSB.

Comment: This could be one of those "manufacturer wants you to over-engineer to avoid any possible warranty complaints" v "real world practicality". In a way, both the manufacturer and your contractor could be right. If it's new construction, and the rest of the house seems to be constructed well, I think screws-only is just fine. In an old house, the mortar wouldn't hurt.

Comment: If it was not stipulated up front to use thinset when installing the cement board, then you would have a hard time forcing them to. BUT, they should give you the option to unscrew, thinset, and rescrew down the boards at additional cost to you and the should also be fair in their pricing and not jack up the price just because they might be irritated.  In my opinion of course.  If we have solid sheathing, we do not typically use thinset under the cement board, but if we have 1x's or something not tight and solid, we add the step of thinset.  Depends on the subfloor.

Comment: @Damon So I need to stipulate the proper installation of the cement board?  The thin set is required by the manufacturer.  Should I also stipulate the cement board be nailed down too?

Comment: @FelixCastor "So I need to stipulate the proper installation of the cement board?"  No, the contractor in their professional opinion has already stipulated the requirements for a proper installation. You just disagree with it. "The thin set is required by the manufacturer."  Required for what?  A proper installation can be done without it. "Should I also stipulate the cement board be nailed down too?" If you wanted it nailed vs screwed, you would need to stipulate that.  If you just want it installed and fastened properly, you need to say nothing with a reputable contractor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a subjective question. Here are the factors as I see them:

1. Hardi apparently doesn't require mortar under its cement board if it's screwed down properly. The guide referenced above seems to be more suggestion than warranty requirement. If the fastener schedule provided is followed closely, problems are not likely to occur. However, a mortared system will be more rigid, potentially reducing tile and grout cracks between floor joists.
2. Your subfloor is OSB, so it's questionable whether a mortar bond is wise at all. OSB is widely considered to be unsuitable as a tile substrate due to its tendency to swell and delaminate from moisture, but this is a bit different. It may have worked out with no ill effects. The mortar would serve to prevent any gaps between the layers of the substrate system, improving stability.
3. Your contract apparently doesn't stipulate mortar in this case. With Hardi's blessing, you probably have no legal standing to insist on mortar.

In my opinion, you'll probably be satisfied with the results if only screws are used. It's difficult to predict how much floor movement will occur with the information provided. That said, a mortar bond would generally be considered a higher-quality installation.

In the end, the decision comes down to your willingness to settle for 95% quality or to deal with the dispute between yourself and your contractor.

Comment: I've agreed to go with just the screws, which is a step up from the roofing nails.  But I agreed in order to keep it civil.  So essentially I settled.

Comment: It's definitely your house and job.  If you do not like something or have concerns, you definitely were right in piping up and saying something to them.  As long as they will stand behind their work and have been in business more than a few years, you should have some peace of mind in assuming they do not want to come back and fix it for free and completed the job in such a way to avoid just that.  Reputability and integrity are important when choosing a contractor for these reasons.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot put tile on OSB because it is not rigid enough. If you do so, eventually it will crack.

You have to remove the OSB and put down high-rigidity plywood, then a membrane then a cement backer board OR use a wood subfloor with a full mortar bed.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Check out the table on page 52 from https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/AWC-2018-Manual-1810.pdf. The plywood and OSB stiffnesses are effectively the same. If you look up deflection requirements for floor assemblies, you'll find that the code prescribes the same L/360 deflection limit that you'll find in backer board floor specifications. It's not coincidence. The backer board people looked up the deflection limits when they were designing their backer board. Without the thinset layer, however, maybe you're right about things eventually failing.

Answer (score -1):

Tyler answered your question nothing really bonds to osb. Even screws eventually get loose on foot traffic. Putting mortar on it causes it to flake. take it up and install plywood 3/4” or install a floating floor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Plenty of things bond to OSB. It's just not a good idea to use _water-based_ products. Solvent-based construction adhesive, for example, bonds extremely well.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing better than glue AND screw. Have them re-do it regardless. They can't say it's worse & they should be there to make you as happy as they can. Especially for being someone actually informed, they should want to impress.

Comment: This answer is better as a comment. It's useful information but doesn't answer the question.